# Magnify an image by a certain ratio in open layers

Tags: openlayers

I have an image that I'm displaying using OpenLayers. Say the distance from point A to point B on my desktop screen which is 1920x1080 is 10cm. Now when I open that image in my laptop screen which is 1366x920, the distance reduces. The distance reduces further on my phone screen. I want to keep the distance between each point the same in the image (basically to magnify it based on the screen size). And the distance should be the same on every layer (zoom) of the image. How can I achieve this?

I'm trying with this example.

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Using Parcel with OpenLayers</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 1300px;
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the js code:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()                                                                                                                    
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
  }),
  pixelRatio: 2
});
```

I tried changing pixelRatio property of ol/map also but there's nothing changing.

Comment: It is not due to the number of pixels, it is because pixels tend to be closer together on smaller devices, and the browser will have no way of knowing the physical size of the device.  If viewing via a 32in TV set or a projecting onto a wall you will probably have the same number of pixels as a 21in monitor.

Comment: Ya. That's why I want to magnify the image to increase the distance between the pixels.

Comment: For OpenLayers you could try experimenting with the map constructor's `pixelRatio` setting.

Comment: I tried adding pixelRation property by using the width of the screen and my desired width. But it also doesn't work.